# Given a database table name, can Django tell me which Model relates to it?

Tags: django, django-models

If I have a Django (1.6) model, I can find out its database table name with `MyModel._meta.db_table`.

Is there any way to do the reverse?

I could do it an ugly way, for instance by hardcoding a large dictionary of all the tables we have to all the models we have, but people won't remember to keep it updated.

If there is no direct way, is there a way to get a list of all the models in the models.pys of the currently installed apps so I can dynamically build that dictionary?

Comment: The database server is PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `django.db.models.get_models()` function:

```
from django.db import models

db_table = 'auth_user'    
mlist = [model for model in models.get_models(include_auto_created=True)
               if model._meta.db_table == db_table]
model = mlist[0] if mlist else None
```

Answer (score 1):

Each model knows its own table and keeps that in `Model._meta.db_table`. You can combine that with [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125107/django-how-can-i-find-a-list-of-models-that-the-orm-knows) to get all the models, so it looks like:

```
from django.db.models import get_models
models = get_models(include_auto_created=True)
table_dict = {model._meta.db_table:model for model in models}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can only accept one answer.