# Django 2.0 getting all model list

Tags: django

I need a list of django models registered, Just like django admin index page. I'm using django 2.0 where `from django.contrib.admin.validation import validate` and `from django.db.models import get_models` is outdated. Advance thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from django.apps import apps
apps.get_models()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_models

For a particular application:

```
from django.apps import apps
apps.all_models['<app_name>']
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1126209/196834

> from django.contrib.admin.validation import validate

It was deprecated.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.7/#modeladmin-validators

Comment: what about `from django.contrib.admin.validation import validate`

Comment: Updated answer.